# Page size for AO Table in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

Can you please tell me how the division into pages occurs when loading data into AO tables? Heap knows that pagination occurs when 32k is reached, but what about AO tables?

Found that the size of the blocks is floating, i.e. not 32k for heap. But nothing is written about AO in the documentation.